# I want to store image in WebContent\upload\news folder and save path in database.in servlet in eclips

Tags: java

[image: I want to upload image in news folder it can be see in image.]
[My code is:]

---

### Coding:

```
String savePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"upload/news/";
File fileSaveDir=new File(savePath); 
if(!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
    fileSaveDir.mkdir();
}
Part part=request.getPart("uploadFile");
String fileName=extractFileName(part);
part.write(savePath+fileName);
```

---

I used this code image is store in `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\RealEstate\upload\news`

Please suggest me how can store image on **WebContent\upload\news** folder

Thank you.....

---